# Can Go spawn and communicate with external processes without starting one OS-thread per external process?

Tags: multithreading, unix, go, concurrency, elixir

**Short version:**

Is it possible in Golang to spawn a number of external processes (shell commands) **in parallel**, such that it does not start one **operating system thread** per external process ... and still be able to receive its output when it is finished?

**Longer version:**

In Elixir, if you use ports, you can spawn thousands of external processes without really increasing the number of threads in the Erlang virtual machine.

E.g. the following code snippet, which starts 2500 external `sleep` processes, is managed by only 20 **operating system threads** under the Erlang VM:

```
defmodule Exmultiproc do
  for _ <- 1..2500 do
    cmd = "sleep 3600"
    IO.puts "Starting another process ..."
    Port.open({:spawn, cmd}, [:exit_status, :stderr_to_stdout])
  end
  System.cmd("sleep", ["3600"])
end
```

(Provided you set `ulimit -n` to a high number, such as 10000)

On the other hand, the following code in Go, which is supposed to do the same thing - starting 2500 external `sleep` processes - does also start 2500 **operating system threads**. So it obviously starts one **operating system thread** per (blocking?) system call (so as not to block the whole CPU, or similar, if I understand correctly):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    for i := 0; i < 2500; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            fmt.Println("Starting sleep ", i, "...")
            cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "3600")
            _, err := cmd.Output()
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            fmt.Println("Finishing sleep ", i, "...")
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }
    fmt.Println("Waiting for WaitGroup ...")
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("WaitGroup finished!")
}
```

Thus, I was wondering if there is a way to write the Go code so that it does the similar thing as the Elixir code, not opening one **operating system thread** per external process?

I'm basically looking for a way to manage at least a few thousand external long-running (up to 10 days) processes, in a way that causes as little problems as possible with any virtual or physical limits in the operating system.

*(Sorry for any mistakes in the codes, as I'm new to Elixir and, and quite new to Go. I'm eager to get to know any mistakes I'm doing.)*

EDIT: Clarified about the requirement to run the long-running processes in parallel.

Comment: This is definitely not an answer to the q as posed, but 1) I know Go can start OS threads to let code keep running during blocking syscalls; I don't know if those threads have, e.g., the big stack allocation you'd tend to associate with a pthreads thread or similar, and 2) it seems plausible to me that the fork+exec for the process would dominate the cost of this operation, and the thread on your program's side is small in comparison.

Comment: @twotwotwo: True, the Go threads don't seem to be terribly heavy-weight. But still, based on my experiments, they still seem to limit the number of external processes that can be practically managed at least more than in Elixir, because of the (small) extra cost.

Comment: A thread is an OS thread, aka a pthread, and is completely separate from goroutines.

Comment: Spawning a subprocess will probably consume up to three goroutines blocked on read/write of the usual file descriptors. The scheduler will also spawn three OS threads to replace those consumed by blocking on those read/write operations. How big of a problem is this ? I don't know but it depends on how many threads is too many, vs how many open file descriptors is too many.

Comment: I tested a 10-thread and 100-thread under go1.5 on Ubuntu amd64. The incremental cost of each of the 90 extra open processes in resident size (roughly, physical memory occupied) worked out to 30.4kb. The virtual-memory size increased 108kb/process, but by definition that doesn't mean 108kb physical RAM occupied. You could run far better tests, but `this > nothing` i figure.

Comment: does someone can confirm and answer why `starting 2500 external sleep processes - does also start 2500 operating system threads.` ?

Comment: @JiangYD -- Yes, Go will start OS threads sometimes. In some places, like its networking stack, Go uses asynchronous syscalls that don't block the OS thread. `exec.Command` apparently uses syscalls that block the OS thread, so Go has to start another thread so `GOMAXPROCS` OS threads can be running Go code. If you want a deeper answer, maybe post an SO question about it (or search around online); potentially too broad a topic for a comment.

Comment: (To Dave's point about open filehandles, with a 1024-file ulimit you can only open 300something processes' `stdin`/`out`/`err`; if the memory-consumption rate from my tiny benchmark holds, that's 10MB RSS, so, yeah, other factors may limit you before exec.Command overhead does.)

Comment: @DaveCheney: True, without changing the default ulimit for open files (which is typically 1024 or so), you will run into this limit far before the number of threads seems to become a problem. I'm still trying to figure out what the other limits are, if any, that I seem to be running into, while increasing the number of processes ... will know more very soon. Maybe it was all the open files limit ...

Comment: Hi all, I have now, after setting ulimit -n very large (1M), managed to start up to 4999 external sleep commands. This results in basically exactly 10K threads to be started for the process. When I go up to 5000 extenal processes, I get a crash. I take this to mean that I'm running into some kind of limit on the number of threads per process amounting to ~10K, though I don't know what it is. That's of course quite a respectable number of processes started though, so I'm not really complaining.

Answer (score 1):

I find that if we not `wait` processes, the Go runtime will not start `2500 operating system threads`. so please use  cmd.Start() other than cmd.Output().

But seems it is impossible to read the process's `stdout` without consuming a OS thread by golang os package. I think it is because os package not use non-block io to read the pipe.

The bottom, following program runs well on my Linux, although it block the process's stdout as @JimB said in comment, maybe it is because we have small output and it fit the system buffers.

```
func main() {
    concurrentProcessCount := 50
    wtChan := make(chan *result, concurrentProcessCount)
    for i := 0; i < concurrentProcessCount; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            fmt.Println("Starting process ", i, "...")
            cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo to sleep $i seconds;sleep $i;echo done;done;")
            outPipe,_ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
            err := cmd.Start()
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            <-time.Tick(time.Second)
            fmt.Println("Finishing process ", i, "...")
            wtChan <- &result{cmd.Process, outPipe}
        }(i)
    }

    fmt.Println("root:",os.Getpid());

    waitDone := 0
    forLoop:
    for{
        select{
        case r:=<-wtChan:
            r.p.Wait()
            waitDone++
            output := &bytes.Buffer{}
            io.Copy(output, r.b)
            fmt.Println(waitDone, output.String())
            if waitDone == concurrentProcessCount{
                break forLoop
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jiang, I was also trying this method, but it also starts equally many threads. In your code, you have to do a sleep of a high number of seconds (like 3600, which is an hour), not just an echo. Also, I think you have to have a cmd.Wait() inside the go-routine, just before wg.Done(), to keep it from finishing until the command is finished. When I fix this, I get the same result, see: https://gist.github.com/samuell/630467732703feefcc81

Comment: but, all i said is not to wait :(  wait will consume a thread and can not reuse  with other goroutines, I think.

Comment: Yeah, but then one can't get the output of those processes, which is one very important point for me, and was mentioned in the question.

Comment: of  course we can read the output of processes, even without wait. this is an other question like `how to read output of process without wait process finish`.

Comment: I maybe did not state it, but I want to run these long-running processes in parallel, not sequentially (will edit the question to clarify). If you know a way to run these long-running processes in parallel, and receive their output in the end, without starting additional threads, I'm very interested in a working code example!

Comment: finally I have time to finish the example, check the update.

Comment: also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346064/go-memory-leak-when-doing-concurrent-os-exec-command-wait/34357485

Comment: This is still incorrect. First, it's incorrect to call Wait until everything is read through the StdoutPipe, since Wait implicitly tries to close the pipe. Second, you're blocking the output of the processes, which will deadlock if the command doesn't sufficiently buffer its output.  Not related to the command: you're leaking time.Tickers - if you need to select on a time interval, use `time.After` or a `time.Ticker` you can Stop, but in this case just use a `time.Sleep`, or even better don't use anything because you shouldn't need to have to sleep to get around a race.