# Go memory leak when doing concurrent os/exec.Command.Wait()

Tags: linux, go, memory-leaks

I am running into a situation where a go program is taking up 15gig of virtual memory and continues to grow. The problem only happens on our CentOS server. On my OSX devel machine, I can't reproduce it.

Have I discovered a bug in go, or am I doing something incorrectly?

I have boiled the problem down to a simple demo, which I'll describe now.  First build and run this go server:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/startapp", startAppHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)
}

func startCmd() {
    cmd := exec.Command("/tmp/sleepscript.sh")
    cmd.Start()
    cmd.Wait()
}

func startAppHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    startCmd()
    w.Write([]byte("Done"))
}
```

Make a file named /tmp/sleepscript.sh and chmod it to 755

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 5
```

And then make several concurrent requests to /startapp. In a bash shell, you can do it this way:

```
for i in {1..300}; do (curl http://localhost:8081/startapp &); done
```

The VIRT memory should now be several gigabytes. If you re-run the above for loop, the VIRT memory will continue to grow by gigabytes every time.

**Update 1:** The problem is that I am hitting OOM issues on CentOS. (thanks @nos)

**Update 2:** Worked around the problem by using `daemonize` and syncing the calls to `Cmd.Run()`. Thanks @JimB for confirming that `.Wait()` running in it's own thread is part of the POSIX api and there isn't a way to avoid calling `.Wait()` without leaking resources.

Comment: VirtualMemory, especially on OSX,  is meaningless. RSS is a little better guide to how much memory the process is suing.

Comment: Tip: [Run()](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Run) executes the process and hangs until it exits.

Comment: I'd also recommend allocating a [pool of goroutines](https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools) to limit the number of processes running at the same time.

Comment: @Zippoxer your points are well received, but Run also hits this same explosion in virtual memory. Run is just shorthand for a .Start() followed by .Wait().  A pool of goroutines is a good architectural choice for many projects, but not really what I'm looking for in this case.

Comment: @JimB, this post is about a CentOS problem, not an OSX problem. The problem is real in that the server stops being responsive when the virtual memory usage hits 40gb.  I suppose you are suggesting that the problem might be happening on OSX as well but I'm not detecting it due to VSS being meaningless on OSX.

Comment: Sorry, misread how centos is the problem here. Are you on a current version of go? Can you run it with gctrace=1 and see what the garbage collector is reporting? And RSS is still going to be a better measure than VSS. Does the system have swap enabled? Does the OOM killer eventually kill the server?

Comment: @JimB Yes, OOM kills the server. The problem happens in git 1.5.1 and 1.5.2, I haven't tried 1.4.x. RSS stays low, and I've ran with go's http profiler and don't see anything large on the heap. I will run with gctrace=1 and report back.

Comment: it not answer your question, but what if not `Wait()` but just `Start()` and return?

Comment: @Gattster I suggest you update the post with this information. That the virtual memory grows to many gigabytes is in itself not any problem. It's fine to grab a lot of virtual memory that might remain unused,, even if us humans don't like seeing such huge numbers in `ps` or `top`..  That you eventually hit OOM, at least if the case is where you do wait until all 300 requests complete and the shell scripts terminate before firing of another test of 300 requests IS a problem.

Comment: @JiangYD if I do what you said, I don't hit any crazy fast memory leak. The problem with the approach you mentioned is the sleepscript.sh processes will hang around as zombies unless I call `Wait()` to clean them up.  I wonder if I should work at a lower level then `Cmd.Start()`.

Comment: @JiangYD also, if you don't call `Wait()`, the virtual memory never grows to a huge size.

Comment: `wait` is a blocking syscall and requires its own thread -- a new one is spawned if there aren't any idle.  Every child process needs to have wait called, that's just part of the POSIX api.

Answer (score 3):

Each request you make requires Go to spawn a new OS thread to `Wait` on the child process. Each thread will consume a 2MB stack, and a much larger chunk of VIRT memory (that's less relevant, since it's virtual, but you may still be hitting a ulimit setting). Threads are reused by the Go runtime, but they are currently never destroyed, since most programs that use a large number of threads will do so again.

If you make 300 simultaneous requests, and wait for them to complete before making any others, memory should stabilize. However if you continue to send more requests before the others have completed, you will exhaust some system resource: either memory, file descriptors, or threads.

The key point is that spawning a child process and calling `wait` isn't free, and if this were a real-world use case you need to limit the number of times `startCmd()` can be called concurrently.

Comment: thank for your answer. It is enlightening, but I think something more buggy is happening here. If I start 300 commands and have them an a wait state, my process is only using a few megs of virt ram. If I start those 300 commands at the exact same time, then we start using 10+gb of VIRT and it grows again only if I do simultaneous starts of commands.

Comment: @Gattster it's the "exact same time" parts that's the problem. If the `wait` is called serially at all, the threads can be reused, but when all the existing threads are in a blocking syscall the runtime needs to spawn a new thread to continue running. Look at the number of threads in your process between your two examples.

Comment: Thanks @JimB. I am considering avoiding this problem by running my long-running subprocesses with `daemonize /tmp/sleepscript.sh`, and synchronizing my calls to `Cmd.Run()`.

Comment: @Gattster `run` also call `wait`.  the examle code in answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948726/can-go-spawn-and-communicate-with-external-processes-without-starting-one-os-thr/33951418?noredirect=1#comment55938173_33951418 may help

Comment: @JiangYD: that's a poor idea for a long running server (which this presumable would be, being an http server), since your example leaves every exec'ed command as a zombie.

Comment: @Gattster why zombies? i not find that. `go run src/main.go 
Waiting for WaitGroup ...
Starting process  0 ...
Starting process  1 ...
Finishing process  0 ...
Finishing process  1 ...
WaitGroup finished!
jiangyd@jiangyd-OptiPlex-3020:~/tmp/testgo$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 9667 pts/16   00:00:00 ps
29933 pts/16   00:00:00 bash
`

Comment: @JiangYD, when your process exits, the zombie entries in the process table are inherited by init, which calls `wait` for you. If the server process doesn't exit, it will just accumulate these zombies. Also, your version doesn't necessarily save OS threads, because file IO is also a blocking syscall and requires its own OS thread.

Comment: @JimB you're right, thanks for point the problems. I have updated the example.